# `activeConversation` is `nil` after transitioning to `.compact` presentation style

Tags: ios, ios10, xcode8, ios-extensions, imessage

## Issue

In a Messages framework app (iOS 10 beta 8), I'm able to access the `activeConversation` in the Messages extension using:

```
    guard let conversation = activeConversation else {
        print("unable to create activeConversation")
        return
    }
```

This works in the `compact` presentation style (on first load) and `expanded` presentation style (always).

After transitioning from `compact` to `expanded`, then to `compact` again, `activeConversation` is always `nil`.

(Note that `activeConversation` is *never* nil in the `expanded` presentation style.)

## Switching View Controllers

### Helper method

In `MessagesViewController.swift`, I'm using this code to switch out view controllers:

```
extension MessagesViewController {
    func switchTo(viewController controller: UIViewController) {

        // Remove existing child view controller
        for child in childViewControllers {
            child.willMove(toParentViewController: .none)
            child.view.removeFromSuperview()
            child.removeFromParentViewController()
        }

        addChildViewController(controller)

        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            controller.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:
                topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ])
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

### Life cycle method override

This `switchTo(controller:)` helper method is called in the `willTransitionTo(presentationStyle:)` override:

```
override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    super.willTransition(to: presentationStyle)

    if presentationStyle == .expanded {
        guard let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "expandedVC") as? ExpandedViewController
        else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate expandedVC")
        }
        controller.delegate = self
        switchTo(viewController: controller)
    }
    else { // .compact
        guard let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "messagesViewController") as? MessagesViewController
        else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate an MessagesViewController")
        }
        switchTo(viewController: controller)
    }
}
```

## Possible problems

1. View hierarchy issue?

   I checked the view hierarchy tool in Xcode, and I haven't noticed anything that sticks out as a problem (although as it's a new tool, I might be reading it incorrectly). I also don't seem to have any memory leaks.
2. Bug in the beta?

   Is anyone else having a problem reliably accessing the `activeConversation`? If so, perhaps it's just a bug in the beta.

Comment: same issue here, I've done a bug report

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue , do you solve it ?, Thanks .

Comment: No workaround that I'm aware of, but I haven't looked at this in a while.